# how to create WCF soap service with List param to be consume from android

Tags: android, wcf, android-ksoap2

I need to pass a `List<string> or List<object>` to consume WCF soap service from Android. I have tried a lot of ways.

When i used below code:

> public class MarshalArray implements Marshal{

```
@Override
public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser parser, String namespace, String name,
        PropertyInfo expected) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

    return GenericType.getObject(parser.nextText());
}

@Override
public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope) {
    envelope.addMapping("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1", "GenericType", GenericType.class, this);
}

@Override
public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object obj)
        throws IOException {
    GenericType sp =  (GenericType) obj;

    writer.startTag("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1", "mydata");       
    for(String str : sp.mydata){
        writer.startTag("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1", "string");
        writer.text(str);
        writer.endTag("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1", "string");

    }       
    writer.endTag("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1", "mydata"); 

    }}
```

With below wcf service:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(WcfService1.GenericType<string>))]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(WcfService1.GenericType<string>))]
    string GetDataList(GenericType<string> objs);
} 

 [DataContract(Name = "GenericType")]
public class GenericType<T>
{
    List<T> data;

    [DataMember]
    public List<T> mydata
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
}
```

Wcf service return a soap fault error like:
Internal service error..

Then I tried in another way:

```
public class Members extends Vector<String> implements KvmSerializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1166006770093411055L;

@Override
public Object getProperty(int index) {
    return this.get(index);
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return this.size();
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo param) {
    param.name = "String";
    param.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int arg0, Object obj) {
    this.add(obj.toString());
}
```

}

With below wcf service:

```
[ServiceContract]
```

public interface IService1
{

```
[OperationContract]

string GetDataList(List<string> objs);
```

}

I got soap fault error which return from wcf service:

```
Deserialization fail...
```

Every time I got an error from wcf service .. I think my `wcf` service got something wrong.
If somebody know the answer .. please kindly answer my question.

Thanks awfully...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer...

I decided used MarshalArray class, not Members(KvmSerializable).

While using MarshalArray,
the problem is in MarshalArray class in android..

here is the old code that occur error:

```
 for(String str : sp.mydata){
    writer.startTag("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1", "string");
    writer.text(str);
    writer.endTag("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1", "string");

}
```

I changed it to like below:

```
for(String str:gt.mydata){
        writer.startTag("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays", "string");
        writer.text(str);
        writer.endTag("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays", "string");               
    }
```

Then it works successfully...

Thanks for your help, stepoverflow. I had to find out the answer myself.... !!